# Mobile Responsive Tiles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have some html/css which works good on screenfly but is misbehaving on actual phone/tablets.

It looks like on the phones my min-width for the tiles isn't respected. Is there something I could do differently to get the same effect?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9747a6a/

**html:**

```
<div class="homepageTiles">
            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <div class="tile">
                <img src="/images/HomepageTiles/EngineTile.png" class="tileImage">

                <div class="caption" style="top: -255px;">
                    <div class="captionLinks">
                        <a href="/engines/onHighway.aspx">ON HIGHWAY</a>
                        <a href="/engines/offHighway.aspx">OFF HIGHWAY</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <img src="/images/HomepageTiles/TransmissionTile.png" class="tileImage">

                <div class="caption" style="top: -255px;">
                    <div class="captionLinks">
                        <a href="/transmissions/onHighway.aspx">ON HIGHWAY</a>
                        <a href="/transmissions/offHighway.aspx">OFF HIGHWAY</a>
                        <a href="/transmissions/remanufactured.aspx">REMANUFACTURED</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <img src="/images/HomepageTiles/GeneratorsTile.png" class="tileImage">

                <div class="caption" style="top: -255px;">
                    <div class="captionLinks">
                        <a href="/generators/ingersollRand.aspx">DOOSAN</a>
                        <a href="/generators/mtuOnSiteEnergy.aspx">MTU ONSITE ENERGY</a>
                        <a href="/generators/packagedGensets.aspx">PACKAGED GENSETS</a>
                        <a href="/generators/preventitiveMaintenance.aspx">PM PROGRAMS</a>
                        <a href="/generators/switchGearAts.aspx">SWITCH GEAR ATS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <a href="/companyInfo/careers.aspx">
                    <img src="/images/HomepageTiles/CareersTile.png" class="tileImage">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.homepageTiles .tile {
margin: .3%;
float: left;
width: 24.4%;
min-width: 225px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.homepageTiles .tileImage {
width: 100%;
}

.homepageTiles .caption {
float: left;
position: absolute;
height: 225px;
width: 100%;
background: url(/images/HomepageTiles/TileBackground.png);
left: 0;
top: -225px;
text-align: center;
}

.homepageTiles .caption .captionLinks {
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-top: 75px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-top: 1px solid #959799;
border-bottom: 1px solid #959799;
}

.homepageTiles .caption .captionLinks a {
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 17px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive in Chrome, but not on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837745/responsive-in-chrome-but-not-on-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a meta tag such as :

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />
```

If the JS solution is undesirable you could use CSS Media Queries to use CSS for each type of device such as:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

**Add the following id's to your HTML**

```
<div id="size" class="tile">
<img id="tile1"  src="http://www.cpower.com/images/HomepageTiles/EngineTile.png" class="tileImage">
<img id="tile2" src="http://www.cpower.com/images/HomepageTiles/TransmissionTile.png" class="tileImage">
<img id="tile3" src="http://www.cpower.com/images/HomepageTiles/GeneratorsTile.png" class="tileImage">
<img id="tile4" src="http://www.cpower.com/images/HomepageTiles/CareersTile.png" class="tileImage">
```

**Then place this JS at the bottom of the page just before `</body>`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var tile = new Array;
tile[0] = document.getElementById('size');
tile[1] = document.getElementById('tile1');
tile[2] = document.getElementById('tile2');
tile[3] = document.getElementById('tile3');
tile[4] = document.getElementById('tile4');
function resize(){
  var w = tile[0].offsetWidth ;
  if (w < 255){w=225;}
  tile[1].style.width= w+'px';
  tile[1].style.height= w+'px';
  tile[2].style.width= w+'px';
  tile[2].style.height= w+'px';
  tile[3].style.width= w+'px';
  tile[3].style.height= w+'px';
  tile[4].style.width= w+'px';
  tile[4].style.height= w+'px';
}
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
//]]>
</script></body></html>
```

I defined the vars tile globally out side of the resize function.  This is so setting the vars is done only one time rather than each time the screen is resized or the mobile screen is rotated.  Could have used a for loop to reduce the size of the code.  This would run a bit slower due to the loop overhead and would not reduce the actual executing machine code size, also due to loop overhead.

Reference:

[Intel Architectures Optimization Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html)

- User/Source Coding Rule 1 Page 15-6,
- User/Source Coding Rule 1 Page 3-9,
- User/Source Coding Rule 2,3,4,5 Page 3-39,
- User/Source Coding Rule 18 Page 8-13,
- User/Source Coding Rule 31 Page 8-22
- User/Source Coding Rule 10,11 Page 3-59

Comment: It looks like moving the images into the div background gives us nothing showing up. Did I miss something: http://jsfiddle.net/a9747a6a/1/

Comment: The height is zero.  The height must be specified.  You will likely need javaScript for that.  I will write the JS and test it

Comment: You see the problem I'm working with. In desktop chrome, the original html/css is a responsive grid which scales up to fit your screen & down as you shrink the screen. With the iphone size going down to one image wide.

On an actual phone/ipad. Instead of breaking the tiles, you get four wide.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a minimum of 255px.  Why not let it scale down to what ever.  I will make some changes and test it using a resizable responsive design viewer.

Comment: The reason for the pixel specified min-width is to give you some break points. On an IPad you end up with three tiles per row. On an iPhone you just have one.

Comment: This works on my Win8 phone.  You can test here on the other mobiles  before you implement my JS:  http://ispeedlink.com/so/bgResponsive/

Comment: Maybe it's something specific to chrome mobile. Which browser do you have on your phone?

Comment: WinPhone 8.1, Explorer 11.  What is not working for you on the iPhone with the JS tweaks?  Are the images still sizing down below 255px?

Comment: Ya, it looks like I can reproduce on the desktop side by pulling up chrome dev tools & hitting the iphone 4 emulation.

I feel like there should be a non-javascript solution to this.